# What is the invention in this patent?

Tags: invention, object-identification

http://www.google.com/patents/US7400295

This is a granted patent for "identification of objects". The authors seem to think that it protects their online and mobile plant classification tool:

http://kukkakasvit.luontoportti.fi/index.phtml?lang=en

What is the invention here really? The application is super simple. The user selects plant characteristics, and the application filters plant species from the database. This is basically a database query with multiple filters. There must be thousands of prior arts.